# Is there a way to auto create columns from Managed Meta Data?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, site-column, term-store

I am very new SharePoint 2013. I am currently creating different term groups that I will be using in my library? After I complete my term group, I have to create a site column for it. Is there a way to auto create a site column and link it to my term group?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via feature.

Check the below link, Here we are going to walk through creating a Managed Metadata column via a feature

[Programmatically create a Managed Metadata Column.](http://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2013/04/01/creating-a-site-column-with-managed-metadata/)

Comment: I am on a restricted network, I cannot access the link above. What is the URL so I can view it later?

Comment: http://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2013/04/01/creating-a-site-column-with-managed-metadata/